# startx with 8 bit color depth not working

Tags: graphics

I need the 8 bit color depth to run some legacy graphic application, in a ubuntu machine (don't care version) but always get error in xorg.log:
`Given depth (8) is not supported by this driver`

in different graphic cards and drivers ( nvidia,intel,amd)
I desperately need help

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 16) are different products to those using the *year.month* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 16 which has 10 years of supported life is a different product to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which had 5 years of *standard* support which has ended, though could be extended via ESM.  Ubuntu's *year* format releases didn't exist in 2014, starting only in 2016.

Comment: "don't care version" changed close reason from EOL to Need more clarity.